# R: transform groupby data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to create a table, where rows = Houses and columns = Man, Woman and total. I've used group_by function, but it shows me the wrong data structure:

`got_chars_bar <- got_chars %>% group_by(house, male) %>% count(house, sort = TRUE)`

and the result is:

[My data after this operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFrsv.png)

The initial dataframe you can check here: https://gitlab.com/hse_mar/mar211s/-/raw/main/data/character-predictions_pose.csv or see a picture of it here (

I want just to have rows = Houses and columns (male, female and total). Help me please, I have a deadline today((

Comment: can u please post the initial dataframe for us to get an idea

Comment: sure! i've added a link

Comment: please check the answer I have posted below , if it is not correct , please comment on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pivot_wider:

```
df <- data.frame(
  house = c("uk", "uk", "NW", "HF", "HS", "HF"),
  male = c(1,0,1,1,1,0),
  n = c(245,182,79,54,49,43)
)

df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = male, values_from = n, values_fill = NA) %>% 
  mutate(total = `0` + `1`)
```

hope it works

Comment: yes! that is a great solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df <- read.csv("path to csv")
dfnew<- df %>% select(house, male)%>%mutate(gender= ifelse(male==1, "MALE", "FEMALE"))
myvars <- c("house", "gender")
dfnew <- dfnew[myvars]
out <- data.frame(addmargins(table(dfnew), 2))
newdf<- dcast(out, house~gender)

output :


[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]